# Reflected radical symbol -- help with indices?

Tags: graphics

I've been playing around with using a reflected radical as a logarithm symbol (see http://www.solidangl.es/2015/04/a-radical-new-look-for-logarithms.html) since I first saw the idea last year.  I'd been hoping that someone more proficient than I would take the time to put something together for typesetting this in latex.  A year later, and it seems like that someone is going to be me.

It may not be the most elegant, but I've hacked something together using \scalebox from the graphicx package.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\FLIPINDEX}[1]{{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$\scriptscriptstyle{#1}$}}}
\newcommand{\FLIPARG}[1]{{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$\,#1$}}}
\newcommand{\usqrt}[2][\phantom{n}]{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$\sqrt[\FLIPINDEX{#1}]{\FLIPARG{#2}}$}}
```

(I'm not sure why defining \FLIPARG and \FLIPINDEX as separate commands made things work, while trying to include exactly that text within the \usqrt definition caused error after error, but it did work, so I'm sticking with it.)

For example, \usqrt{2^x} will give the log of 2^x.  There are some questionable vertical spacing issues with the placement of the horizontal line, but I'm willing to live with them.

The big problem that I am not sure how to resolve is the vertical placement of the index.  In theory, you can use \usqrt[2]{x} or \usqrt[10]{x} to get different bases for the logarithm.  The problem is that my flip-and-flip-again procedure causes the index to be exactly where it originally would be vertically -- which is now the middle of the square-root symbol.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to move the base of the index to the baseline of the expression?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While this may be an interesting problem on the TeX side, I strongly disagree with the proposed notation, because logarithms are inherently distinct from roots.

Comment: The reason it does not work when you substitute the text directly from `\FLIPARG` into `\usqrt` is that it places an optional argument within an optional argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented, the reason it does not work when you substitute the text directly from `\FLIPARG` into `\usqrt` is that it places an optional argument (of `\scalebox`) within an optional argument of `\sqrt`. The LaTeX parsing algorithm cannot handle that type of syntax.

To move the index down, I did a simple `\raisebox` on the flipped index.  It is not as simple as moving it to the baseline, because the flipped radical will not always be at the same vertical height, but will shift vertically based on the height of the content (i.e., the presence of sub and superscripts).  Thus, what can be achieved this way is to make the index at the same location relative to the root sign.

I also modified the kern of `\FLIPARG`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\FLIPINDEX}[1]{{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$\scriptscriptstyle{#1}$}}}
\newcommand{\FLIPARG}[1]{{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$\mkern2mu#1$}}}
\newcommand{\usqrt}[2][\phantom{n}]{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$\sqrt[\raisebox{4pt}{\FLIPINDEX{#1}}]{\FLIPARG{#2}}$}}
\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt[3]{2^x}
\usqrt[10]{2^x}
\usqrt[3]{x^2}
\usqrt[3]{2x_i}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]